# using git-svn with XCode to commit and fetch

Tags: git-svn

we are using svn in our company and since XCode doesn't support that anymore i have been looking at svn-git. But i didn't fully understand it. Can i make it so, that committing from XCode will also commit the changes to the svn repository or would i still have to run commands from terminal aftwerwards?